# Android too much work on main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am creating an MP3player app as a side project.

I have an activity called "AddPlaylistActivity" which handles the creation and addition of playlists from all songs available on the phones local storage(s). It works fine if I do not try to add alot of songs to the same playlist at once. It handles <15 fine, but >20-ish and it crashes completely stating in the log that there may be too much work being done on the main thread.

I have tried making a new thread for saving the playlist running on the UI thread as that is the only allowed way to do it because otherwise i get the red warning that the operation MUST be executed on the main thread.

I have also tried running a UI thread and inside run another "normal" thread that handles the playlist addition.

My playlist addition is made as follows:

Here I have the navigation menu where I can click the "Add playlist" to open the add playlist activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.addPlaylist) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MP3Player.this, AddPlaylistActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.allSongs) {
        allSongs();
    }
    else {
        updateSongList(navigationView.indexOfChild(menuItem.getActionView()));
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

In the AddPlaylistActivity I have functionality for adding songs to a To-Be playlist. But that code works fine, the most interesting part I think is the method I use to return a bundle of the songs, back to the main activity:

```
public void createPlaylist(String playlistName, ArrayList<Song> newPlaylistSongsArray) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("array", newPlaylistSongsArray);
    returnIntent.putExtra("playListName", playlistName);
    returnIntent.putExtras(b);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

This bundle is sent to the onActivityResult method that takes the bundle and saves the songs of the new playlist as a new playlist "file" or data in the shared preferences on the phone. I guess it's more of a reference list of which songs are supposed to be in which list.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String newPlaylistName = data.getStringExtra("playListName");
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            final PlayList newPlaylist = new PlayList();
            newPlaylist.setSongsInPlayList((ArrayList<Song>) b.getSerializable("array"));
            newPlaylist.setPlayListName(newPlaylistName);

            /*
            When storing a new playlist, the next and previous song references
            needs to be nulled in order for them to be able to be saved in the
            preferences.
            These next and prev references are restored when a playlist is loaded
            again from the preferences.
             */
            for (Song s : newPlaylist.getSongsInPlayList()) {
                s.setNext(null);
                s.setPrev(null);
            }

            /*
            Add the new playlist to the navigation view and give it an icon
            and a click listener.
             */
            MenuItem newPlaylistItem = navigationMenu.add(newPlaylistName);
            newPlaylistItem.setIcon((ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save, null)));
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MP3Player.this);

            /*
            Now, store the new playlist in the shared preferences.
             */
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            prefsEditor.putString("PLAYLISTS", null);
            prefsEditor.apply();

            ArrayList<PlayList> playListsInMenu;
            String playlistString = prefs.getString("PLAYLISTS", null);
            /*
            Check shared prefs for existing playlists.w
             */
            if (playlistString == null) {
                playListsInMenu = new ArrayList<>();
                playListsInMenu.add(newPlaylist);
            } else {
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<PlayList>>() {
                }.getType();
                playListsInMenu = gson.fromJson(playlistString, type);
                playListsInMenu.add(newPlaylist);

            }
            String json = gson.toJson(playListsInMenu);
            prefsEditor.putString("PLAYLISTS", json);
            prefsEditor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(MP3Player.this, "New Playlist Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(MP3Player.this, "Shit went wrong yo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not quite sure which part of this sequence that causes the crash. I don't think it's the createPlaylist because it simply returns a bundle to the main activity. I think the problem is in my onActivityResult method because here the bundle is unpacked, put to JSON format and stored in the shared prefs all while the main thread is still up and doing it's thing so to speak.

I am guessing that's where my problem is, but I do not know how to solve this.

I have also tried using an AsyncTask, but in order for it to work i have to make the asyncTask class abstract so I can pass my Intent Data from the onActivityResult to the asynctask class and do operations in it. This however makes me unable to execute the asynctasak because it cannot be abstract.

Does anyone have any suggestions or work arounds?

Comment: Instead of managing your playlists and songs across different activities, consider using only one class to control everything, such as PlaylistManager.java, or other name.

Comment: Also, operations like foreach over large lists, JSON parsing and SharedPreferences editing can be time-consuming, so consider putting them inside doInBackground methods of AsyncTasks

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, wouldn't the code be much simpler if you just used `SQLiteOpenHelper` by making a nested `AsyncTask` class in one `Activity` instead of sharing the logic across two activities.

Comment: @ShababbKarim As I stated, I tried using an asyncTask in my main activity, but I can't seem to get it to work since if i change the doInbackground method, i have to make the AsyncTask abstract, which prevents me from calling it. How could I go about making an asyncTask that can take Intent data as a parameter?

Comment: You can't do that in `AsyncTask`. You are creating a playlist in `AddPlaylistActivity` by the method `createPlaylist`, isn't it? My solution is to scrap the `AddPlaylistActivity` and let a `Asynctask` class's `doInBackground` method handle creating of playlist. Also it would be much better if you used Android's SqliteDatabase instead of `SharedPreference`. I think you just have to change the way you are getting stuff done.